# Does Realm .net Implementation Support Local Export

Tags: c#, .net, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've looked in the API as best I can but I'm wondering if there is a way to back up a Realm .net db on device (Android, iOS etc) using export or something similar. Need that functionality more than cloud sync, which I know is another way to back up.

Any.net realm libray device-side backup implementation thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Realm file is just a file - if it isn't open, you can back it up using the filesystem API. If a Realm instance is open, copying the file is not safe as it is not an atomic operation and the file contents may change while copying.

If you need to perform a backup while a Realm is open, you can use [Realm.WriteCopy](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/dotnet/10.0.0-beta.1/reference/Realms.Realm.html#Realms_Realm_WriteCopy_Realms_RealmConfigurationBase_) to do that. For example, something like this:

```
// This is the Realm you want to backup
var myRealm = Realm.GetInstance(...);

// Store the file in Backups/myRealm.backup
var myRealmPath = myRealm.Config.DatabasePath;
var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(myRealmPath);
var backupPath = Path.Combine(folder, "Backups", "myRealm.backup");

var backupConfig = new RealmConfiguration(backupPath);

// You can also encrypt the backup
// backupConfig.EncryptionKey = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, ..., 64 };

myRealm.WriteCopy(backupConfig);
```